# CSS grid, space right side

Tags: html, grid

This is my grid:

```
    display: grid
  grid-template-columns: 5fr 30fr 30fr 30fr 5fr
  grid-template-rows: 100vh 50vh 50vh 20vh
  grid-template-areas: "moviehead moviehead moviehead moviehead moviehead" ". services services services ." ". event event event ." ". contact contact contact ."
```

As you can see I got one "spacer" on each side of the grid under moviehead. But running the code in Firefox (latest) I dont get the white space that I want, what simple error have I created?

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd paste your html code in here, too, with your named divs, and all the other CSS.

Comment: I cracked the error this morning, it was one row to few.

Comment: Can you post your answer (as an answer) so that others can benefit from it?